# adding external developer to development team

Tags: ios, xcode

We would like to outsource a iOS project, however, we definitely don't want to share our private signing key or Apple developer account credential to external developer.

Now, the external developer ask me to add him as a team member of "Development team" in the project (I mean in Xcode, the signing section needs to select a development team.) so that he could use our certificate to sign the project and run on real device.

But I am not sure is there any risk to add him as a development team member in Apple Developer portal? If so, what could be the risk?

Answer (score 1):

There is no risk. You can set permissions of the team member so that he can't do anything but look at stuff in iTunesConnect, but still have the permissions to download the provisioning profiles and development certificates that he needs to run the app on his device.

In iTunesConnect, click on Users & Roles, assign the roles you would like your new member to be.

Refer to Apple's documentation on Roles to decide which roles you would like the new member to have: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: Could you pleas also point me on the correct way of adding external developer to the team for my case?

Comment: Here is Apple's documentation for adding users to an account: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html

Comment: OK, I read it, but it is unclear to me which role I should assign to the external developer if I want him to only look stuff and download development provisioning profile and certificate, could you please let me know which role I should use for him?

Comment: But here : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html  it says I should add the developer through developer.apple.com , not ituneconnect, I get confused now, could you please clarify?

Comment: @Leem I updated my answer, refer to the link in the answer.